# PHP/Javascript database displayed in a div over-writing the previous display

Tags: javascript, php

How can I display database records in a `div` every time overwriting the previous display? These records should be displayed in a random manner and for a specified count using a `for` loop.

The roll of records should start when a user presses 'start' like shown below.
The user interface of rolling numbers:

[image]

I am making a draw application. It is a web-based application that will be communicating with oracle database. The picture above shows the user interface; how I envisioned this is to be able to pull ids (numbers in red), from the database when a user presses START button and being able to clear the numbers when they press RESET button. My main challenge is to display numbers in a random manner for a specified period of time or count. What I have done so far is the GUI, am a newbie and need help to implement this logic in PHP/Javascript/Ajax.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Competition Draw</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/…; 
    <script src="scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="" alt="My logo">
    </div>
    <header>
      <h2>DRAW AND WIN</h2>
    </header> 

    <aside>
      <p>Draw Type:
      <select name="draw_type">
        <option value="first_draw">First draw</option>
        <option value="grand_draw">Grand draw</option>
      </select>
      </p>
      <p>State:
      <select name="state">
        <option value="all">All</option>
        <option value="michigan">Michigan</option>
        <option value="missisipi">Missisippi</option>
        <option value="ontario">Ontario</option>
        <option value="washington">Washington</option>
        <option value="losangeles">Los Angeles</option>
        <option value="carolina">Carolina</option>
        <option value="alaska">Alaska</option>
        <option value="texas">Texas</option>
        <option value="newjersey">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="newyork">New York</option>
      </select>
      </p>
    </aside>

  <article>
    <div class="roll">
      <h1>001062009</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <input type="submit" value="start">
      <input type="submit" value="reset">
    </div>
    <div id="flip">
      <h3>Winner's Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="panel">
      <p>Name : <b>One Muzo</b></p>
      <p>Account No : <b>001062009</b></p>
      <p>Branch Name : <b>Los Angeles branch</b></p>
      <p>Current Balance : <b>10,000.70 <i>USD</i></b></p>
    </div>

  </article>
    <footer>Copyright©2016</footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What are you using to display content? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your topic is not clear : how can a database would be displayed ? I never saw this, you should precise : what kind of data, what does "start" should do, "reset", ... And like @cascer1 said, show a bit more of interest by linking your code.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You are always able to edit your question using the [edit] button. You should normally update it with code using that facility and not put it in the ephemeral comments. I have moved your code to the correct place for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have basic knowledge of jquery, html and ajax.

Here are the scenario:-

Start button:- Call an ajax function which will fetch data from database. Check response and replace html of current div.

Reset Button:- Just empty html, value of the div/input.

Comment: I have basic knowledge of jquery and ajax and more knowledgeable in html. <p>Thanks for the response.</p>